# How to subtract two columns from different table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, subtraction

I have two tables data which contain id, features and mean which contain value .features consists of 13849 value.

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|            features|
+---+--------------------+
| 10|[5.82797050476074...|
| 20|[2.75361084938049...|
| 30|[-2.2027940750122...|
| 40|[4.20199108123779...|
| 50|[2.69677162170410...|
| 60|[2.65212917327880...|
| 70|[3.83443570137023...|
| 80|[0.45349338650703...|
| 90|[3.12527608871459...|

+---+--------------------+
```

second table:

```
+------------------+
|             value|
+------------------+
|2.4848911616270923|
|2.4848911616270923|
|2.4848911616270923|
|2.4848911616270923|
|2.4848911616270923|
|2.4848911616270923|
|2.4848911616270923|
|2.4848911616270923|
|2.4848911616270923|
+------------------+
```

code:

```
case class DataClass(id: Int, features:Double)
val newDataDF = spark.read.parquet("file:///usr/local/spark/dataset/model/data/user/part-r-00000-7d55ba81-5761-4e36-b488-7e6214df2a68.snappy.parquet").toDF()//.toDF()//.map(_.split(",")).map(p => DataClass(p(0).trim.toInt, p(1).trim.toDouble)).toDF()
newDataDF.withColumn("features", ((newDataDF("features")-2.4848911616270923)/1.8305483113586494))
```

give me error

> cannot resolve '(`features` - 2.4848911616270923D)' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(`features` - 2.4848911616270923D)' (array and double).
>   How to solve it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, but the error message is fairly explicit: you're trying to substract doubles from arrays.
And indeed, your `features` column looks like it contains arrays.

Comment: i want to subtract features from value .is there any way to convert array[Double] to Double ?

Comment: can you add the output of first dataframe with .show(false)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use:

```
val dfWithCalculatedFeatures = newDataDF.withColumn("features", (col("features")(0) - 2.4848911616270923)/1.8305483113586494)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer .